# odbc_exec datetime error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, odbc

I have an error when running a stored procedure that contains dates as input.

My query is:

```
$query = "asistencia_virtual '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'";
```

In Management Studio and it works perfect.

I have only problems with queries that are dated, the others work great.

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]
> Error de sintaxis al convertir una cadena de caracteres a datetime., SQL state 22008 in SQLExecDirect

Comment: what version of sql server you are using?

Comment: @JW. SQL Server Native Client 10.0 - That's 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [(reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
asistencia_virtual {d'2012-01-01'}, {d'2012-12-31'}
```

Comment: Thanks {d'2012-12-31'} fix it!

Answer (score 2):

As you've found out, `yyyy-mm-dd` is not a safe date format. Here is why:

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
SELECT MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-12')); -- yields 12, not 1
GO
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-12-31');
```

The first query yields `12` instead of `1`, since it interprets this as `yyyy-dd-mm`. The second query yields:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

The ONLY safe format for date only datetime string literals is `yyyymmdd`. Here is how your code should look (adding the obligatory `EXEC` and `dbo.` prefix):

```
$query = "EXEC dbo.asistencia_virtual '20120101', '20121231';";
```

For a lot more information on common date/time query problems:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: While I would never doubt you, how is that not sane? Isn't that the ISO 8601 date spec? Wouldn't this be more classified as a failure of the parsing engine than a "localization" issue? Is that a failure on the part of ... I can't even fathom. I'm glad you included the connect issue in your blog post. Hopefully this goes away in the near future.

Comment: @jcolebrand This has to do with adhering to localization. Allegedly, when someone has indicated their language is `FRENCH`, the SQL Server team (way back when) deemed that that must mean they want `yyyy-dd-mm`. I wouldn't try to draw ISO standards too far into this either, because most customers don't know or don't care - 99% of customers use either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`...

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to dates, the best practice is to give the written alternative to the month - that way there is no chance that the day and month can get mixed up along the way. Try inputting the dates as string in the following format:

'dd MMM yyyy'

```
$query = "asistencia_virtual '01 Jan 2012', '31 Dec 2012'";
```

Comment: it always works, in spanish you would use ene (enero) instead of jan if the sql server is set to spanish

Comment: The problem is you can have two users in the same application, one with language Spanish, one with English. Do you really want to have some kind of switch to hard-code the month names based on the language?

Comment: That's what you would use localisation for. The sql server will only be in one language. You pass the SQL server the language required and your front end displays localised dates.